# How to issue SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol?

Tags: python, python-requests, socks

I run this python code, This code correct in my laptop but after upload on the server show this error:

`OS in server is: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS`

```
flight_page = f.get("https://{}/Search/{}-{}/{}".format(self.site, self.from, self.to, date), timeout=30, verify=False)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 467, in get
return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 455, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 558, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 385, in send
raise SSLError(e)
SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
```

My code is:

```
import requests
import socks
import socket

socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "{}".format(proxy_row['ip']), proxy_row['port'])
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
f = requests.Session()

flight_page = f.get("https://{}/Search/{}-{}/{}".format(self.site, self.from, self.to, date), timeout=30, verify=False)
```

How to issue this

Comment: What is the output of: `python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"` on your laptop and your server?

Comment: @zwer ,Hi, On the Laptop: `OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016` and in server is `OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014`

Comment: @zwer How to issue this error?

Comment: I thought it was due to an old OpenSSL error... Try updating the `requests` module on your server: `python -m pip install requests --upgrade`

Comment: @zwer Thank you but after run this code, show this error: `SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='website.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /Search/... (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(8, '_ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol'),))`

Comment: As a last resort, I'd attempt updating OpenSSL and its Python link. Search on Google how to do that for your server's OS.